# Call Controller Action on button click

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

How to call controller action in button click using JavaScript or JQuery or AJAX what ever. I have one controller and I want to create a function to call controller method when button is pressed

```
[ResponseType(typeof(AKONTA))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAKONTA(string id)
        {
            AKONTA aKONTA = db.AKONTAS.Find(id);
            if (aKONTA == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Ne postoji A_KONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }

            return Ok(aKONTA);
        }
```

I create a function like this but doesnt work, always show this message

```
alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");


@section scripts{
    <script>
        function aKontoSubmit() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                URL: "/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val(),
                // data: $('form').serialize(),
                dataType: "application/xml",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Odlicno")
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<br /><br />
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>A_KONTO</label>
        @*<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="AKONTO BROJ" placeholder="Unesite broj AKONOTO">*@
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="AKONTO BROJ" placeholder="Unesite broj AKONOTO" id='AkontasId'>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary" id="aKonto" onClick='aKontoSubmit()'>Provjeri</a>
    </div>
</form>


@section scripts{
    <script>
        function aKontoSubmit() {
            $("#aKonto").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    URL: "/api/Akontas/",
                    data: { id: $('#AkontasId').val() },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("Odlicno")
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert(Error);
                       // alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

```
<br /><br />
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>A_KONTO</label>
        @*<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="AKONTO BROJ" placeholder="Unesite broj AKONOTO">*@
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="AKONTO BROJ" placeholder="Unesite broj AKONOTO" id='AkontasId'>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="aKonto" onClick='aKontoSubmit()'>Provjeri</a>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function aKontoSubmit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            URL: "/api/Akontas/",
            data: {id : $('#AkontasId').val()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Odlicno")
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm It seems like it doesnt hit controller :/ 
Again same error

Comment: Try then to put `<HttpPost>` on the same place where you have `[ResponseType(typeof(AKONTA))]`, on the "header" of the method and let's see if it hits the controller

Comment: Nop, Againe same problem.

Comment: To get a more specific error, you can change your AJAX error as follows and tell me what you get: `error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }`

Comment: Index:70 Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at Object.error (Index:70)
    at fire (jquery-3.4.1.js:3291)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-3.4.1.js:3421)
    at done (jquery-3.4.1.js:9535)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.js:9785)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: aKontoSubmit is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: Ok let's start again making sure it works as expected: First of all, when you click the button, does it enter to `function aKontoSubmit()`?

Comment: Noo, it doesnt enter to function aKontoSubmit()

Comment: Open the Chrome console (F12) and make sure you haven't got any syntax errors on your code. If there are some syntax errors it will appear on the bottom a red-coloured message. If you haven't got any, try removing `asp-action="Index"` from your <a> element and see if it enters the function then :)

Comment: I open console, there is no error, and I delete asp-action="Index" but again same problem

Comment: Maybe your **scripts** section is not being rendered, can you see it through the Chrome console -> Elements tab? It should appear there with all your HTML code as you will know.

Comment: When I create a application.js file and put javascript code inside and rende in BoundleConfig againg same problem

Comment: Ok, remove the `@section scripts{ }` wrapper and leave directly all the <script> you already have. (It's the same code but without the @section, this way the script will render automatically) Then let's see if it hits the aKontoSubmit() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199237/discussion-between-nestor-carreno-gimeno-and-xerror).

Comment: I removed 'section script' but again noting happened. In Chrome console there is no error but I only get message alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");

Comment: @ Néstor Carreño Gimeno Thank you bro for helping, I resolve problem :)

Comment: Glad you did it! I've just read your answer, keep the good work!

Answer (score 1):

After a couple hours of debugging and searching I found that I forget to put

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val();
```

This is location where should redirect if item exsist in database

And URL call need to be modified as well

```
URL: "/api/Akontas/GetAKONTA",


 function aKontoSubmit() {

        $.ajax({          
            type: "GET",            
            URL: "/api/Akontas/GetAKONTA",
            data: { id: $('#AkontasId').val() },
            contentType: "data/xml; charset=utf-8",  
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }
        });
    }
```